# Inserting value into foreign key record

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, foreign-keys

I'm making band discography organizer form using C# / Visual Studio that's connected to a SQL Server database with three tables (`Bands, Album, Tracks`). I think I created the tables correctly as far as the foreign keys go but I'm having a hard time inserting the correct value into the foreign keys of the `Album` and `Track` tables.

Here's how I created my tables:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Bands') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE Bands 
    (
         id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
         name VARCHAR(50)
    )

IF OBJECT_ID('Albums') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE Albums 
    (
         id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
         title VARCHAR(50),
         release_date DATE,
         band_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Bands(id)
    )

IF OBJECT_ID('Tracks') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE Tracks 
    (
         id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
         title VARCHAR(50),
         album_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Albums(id),
         band_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Bands(id)
    )
```

And here's how I'm currently trying to add values into the `Albums` table. I'm passing an `Album` object which contains the album title and release date, and also the string of a band name which has already been added to the `Bands` table:

```
    public static void InsertAlbumName(Album albumTitle, string bandName) 
    {
        string connString = "my connection string here";
        string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO Albums ([Title], [Release_Date], [band_id]) VALUES (@title, @releaseDate, (SELECT id FROM Bands WHERE name = '@name'))";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NText);
                cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = bandName;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.NText);
                cmd.Parameters["@title"].Value = albumTitle.AlbumTitle;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@releaseDate", SqlDbType.Date);
                cmd.Parameters["@releaseDate"].Value = albumTitle.ReleaseDate;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't get an error and all the values are being added except the foreign key `band_id`, which remains `NULL`. Let me know there's more I can add. Having a hard time articulating what I'm asking...

Comment: If band_id is null, then a band with name @name doesn't exist in your database.

Comment: Ohhhh okay so I'm either passing the string incorrectly or (more likely) I'm not using the parameters correctly. Thanks!

Comment: You certainly shouldn't be using `NTEXT` - its been recommended to use nvarchar(max) for years now. That won't be your problem, but something to improve on.

Comment: Noted! Also, I realized the issue was I had single quotes around @name. Thanks for the push in the right direction!

Comment: Haha - yes that will do it!

Comment: You have defined `Albums.Title`  as `varchar(50)` - so the parameter should be `cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50) ;` - `Ntext` is triply wrong - it's a **unicode** type (while `varchar` isn't), it's 2 GB long while your column really supports 50 chars, and it's deprecated..... **IF** you define parameter types - which is a great thing to do!! - pay attention to the datatypes and lengths of your columns - the parameters need to match the tables

Comment: Thank you! I started this project to try and learn sql server and how to connect to it via c#/visual studio so that’s helps a bunch